# Can't locate an available class with Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium

Here is the html element I"m trying to connect with

```
 <div class="_uX kno-fb-ctx" aria-level="3" role="heading" data-hveid="39" data-ved="0ahUKEwiesciCl_PWAhVDRCYKHbS3B4AQtwcIJygAMAI"><div class="_XWk">Canis lupus familiaris</div><div class="_Tfc"></div></div>
```

I'm trying to connect to the class `_uX kno-fb-ctx`:

Using this line

```
driver.find_element_by_class_name("_uX kno-fb-ctx")
```

or

```
driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("div. _uX kno-fb-ctx")
```

results in a :

```
 selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element: ._uX kno-fb-ctx
```

However I can connect to the inner-html:

```
 driver.find_element_by_class_name('_XWk')
```

So something wrong with my syntax that is disabling me to connect to the outer class?

Here is my code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from fake_useragent import UserAgent
from send2trash import send2trash
import requests
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
import requests
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

ua = UserAgent()
QUERY = 'Scientific name of  dog'
headers = {'User-Agent': ua.firefox}

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("http://www.google.com")
input_element = driver.find_element_by_name("q")
input_element.send_keys( QUERY)
input_element.submit()
time.sleep(3)


WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
EC.visibility_of_element_located(((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.g"))))

driver.find_element_by_class_name("_uX kno-fb-ctx")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`find_element_by_class_name("_uX kno-fb-ctx")` is invalid syntax as compound class names are not permitted.

`div. _uX kno-fb-ctx` is also not valid CSS selector

You can try

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("div._uX.kno-fb-ctx")
```

Also note that there is no sense in `time.sleep(3)` if you use `WebDriverWait()` on the next line

Comment: Ah! I forgot that spaces mean multiple classes. Thank you.

Comment: @Moondra Spaces in a CSS selector doesn't mean multiple classes, it means a descendant. `.` indicates a class name in CSS selectors... unless you are talking about spaces in the class attribute in the HTML.

Comment: @Andersson Sorry for the confusion. I meant that to say that  `_uX`  and `kno-fb-ctx` are actually two separate classes (indicated by the space) That's why we need a `.` period in between.